# Missing features compiling NTP vs installing already built

Tags: ntp

I have found that if I compile NTP myself, the package ntp-keygen is missing Autokey authentication features.

The help screen of my compiled ntp is as follows:
[image]

Whereas if I just apt-get install ntp, the ntp-keygen help looks like this:
[image]

From the documentation, these features should be enabled by default.  This is confirmed when I check ./configure --help:
[image]

*the + symbol means it is enabled by default

Comment: As per the docs, you may also need to build and install OpenSSL libraries. As the missing options are related to crypto operations, this seems very likely in your case.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: Hmm I thought OpenSSL is installed if you have SSH?  I will take a look at the OpenSSL now.

Comment: Specifically you need the development packages for openssl installed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fix was to correctly specify the location of the library.

Comment: No, that was the cause. The fix was to correctly specify the location of the library, which this answer is not saying how to do.